# Can I append to a file using binary's Data.Binary?

Tags: haskell, binary, append, disk

I've got a `[Something]` value, I'd like to save this value to disk every **n** seconds.

However this value could have a large number of elements, and writing the complete value each time could potentially cause unnecessary disk wear. Therefore, I'm looking to append to a file instead.

The list itself (`[Something]`) would always be appended to, and wouldn't have it's 'original' content modified in any way.

Is it possible to use `Data.Binary` for this purpose?

I did find the `append`(http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.8.6.0/docs/Data-Binary-Builder.html#v:append) function, but this does not seem to fulfill the above usecase.

If it's not possible, is there an alternative library I can use?

Comment: Hard disks don't really wear out when repeatedly writing data. Though it _is_ a waste of time of course. (SSDs might wear out, though this isn't really that much of an issue anymore.) — `binary` isn't really concerned much with (non-)strictness, that's more a property of the underlying data structure. And with a lazy bytestring, this _might_ actually work out the way you want. For proper control of “lazy IO”, you should check out one of the dedicated libraries; [`conduit`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit) or [`pipes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes).

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm a bit confused as to why you've mentioned strictness, how does that relate to appending to files?

Comment: Oh there is `toLazyByteString :: Builder -> ByteString`, which would give me a `Bytestring` which I can then append to the file using `appendFile`. Will give this a try tomorrow!

Comment: [appendFile](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:appendFile), but you would probably have to append the new elements before (or after) adding them into the list

Comment: I think the question misses the critical information: Is the `[Something]` list append-only as well, or do you change its contents in a different fashion?

Comment: Thanks @nh2 I too think that was critical to the question! And yes the list would be append only.

Answer (score 1):

How large is your list? If it's millions, it makes sense to append, provided that you're able to extract the newly added elements at each round. If it's thousands or less, then it's probably easier to just write all of them every time.

It seems that you could do appending to a file yourself. That is, [encode](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.8.6.0/docs/Data-Binary.html#v:encode) the newly added elements into a `ByteString` and [append](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:appendFile) them to a file. (Make **sure** that only one process at a time is doing that!)

And then when reading the file, iterate [`decodeOrFail`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.8.6.0/docs/Data-Binary.html#v:decodeOrFail), feeding it the unconsumed input from the previous call, until you parse everything and reach an empty `ByteString`.

---

Somewhat orthogonal, I found using [safe-copy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safecopy) very helpful. It allows making serialization forward/backward compatible very easy.

If you don't mind writing the whole data all the time, then [acid-state](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/acid-state) gives you very strong guarantees about your data. It also has integration with safe-copy.